# Unable to install package from pub.dev

Tags: flutter

I'm really new to flutter, I want to install a plugin from pub.dev (https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar/install)

The manual says that I need to execute below command,

> flutter pub add table_calendar

But what I've got is

> Could not find a subcommand named "add" for "flutter pub".
>
> Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter  -h') for available flutter
> commands and options.

I have tried to search for the solution why my flutter cannot use "add" command but not found yet.

Here is my flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on macOS 12.1 21C52 darwin-arm, locale en-TH)
    • Flutter version 1.22.4 at /Users/kalvin/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 1aafb3a8b9 (2 years, 8 months ago), 2020-11-13 09:59:28 -0800
    • Engine revision 2c956a31c0
    • Dart version 2.10.4
```

Comment: Does `flutter pub remove ...` work? What about `flutter pub get`?

Comment: Your flutter version is too old. I recommend running "flutter upgrade" and try pub get again.

Answer (score 1):

Your Flutter version is *waaaay* old. These commands introtuced in here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72805

Try upgrading Flutter.